# How would you describe a Matrix in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix

Don't get me wrong, I know how to use a Matrix in AS3, for example at the createGradientBox() I have these Parameters:

```
matrix.createGradientBox(width, height, rotation, x, y);
```

But I am interested about how a Matrix works behind the scene? How would you describe a Matrix? THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of the tutorials which I liked

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/understanding-affine-transformations-with-matrix-mathematics/